# User defined in the inventory is not respected

Tags: linux, ssh, ansible

I am new in Ansible and I am trying to create a simple empty file from my main PC to two Virtual machines on my pc using VirtualBox.
The two VMs have 2 adapters (one NAT network, so they can see each other and have different IPs, and the second adapter is Host only adapter). They have SSH and my main PC can connect via SSH and can ping the vm with the ping command.
I have also created inventory file called *myhosts*:

```
[servers]
user1 ansible_host=192.168.56.4
user2 ansible_host=192.168.56.3
```

and here is the playbook that creates an empty file

```yaml
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:
  - name: create an empty file
    file:
      path: "/home/test_file.txt"
      state: touch
    become: yes
```

When I run this command

```sh
$ ansible-playbook -i myhosts -K playbook1.yml
```

This is the output:

```
BECOME password: 

PLAY [all] *************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *************************************************************
fatal: [user1]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: david@192.168.56.4: Permission denied (publickey,password).", "unreachable": true}
fatal: [user2]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: david@192.168.56.3: Permission denied (publickey,password).", "unreachable": true}

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************
user1                      : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
user2                      : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Note this line: "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: david@192.168.56.4 and david@192.168.56.3". david is my main user on my PC, not on the VMs.

It should be user1@192.168.56.4 and user2@192.168.56.3 (Those are the usernames on the two VMs I have)

**What I tried:**
I tried using the command

```sh
$ ansible-playbook -i myhosts -K playbook1.yml --users user2
```

and it works but only on the second user.

also I tried copy the VM ssh key and paste it to VM root with

```sh
cp -R /home/user1/.ssh /root/.ssh
cp -R /home/user2/.ssh /root/.ssh
```

and when I run this command

```sh
$ ansible-playbook -i myhosts -K playbook1.yml --user root
```

Works only on one VM and not the second VM

```sh
$ ansible-playbook -i myhosts -K playbook1.yml --user root
BECOME password: 

PLAY [all] *************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *************************************************************
fatal: [user1]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: root@192.168.56.4: Permission denied (publickey,password).", "unreachable": true}
[DEPRECATION WARNING]: Distribution debian 10.8 on host user2 should use 
/usr/bin/python3, but is using /usr/bin/python for backward compatibility with 
prior Ansible releases. A future Ansible release will default to using the 
discovered platform python for this host. See https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10
/reference_appendices/interpreter_discovery.html for more information. This feature
 will be removed in version 2.12. Deprecation warnings can be disabled by setting 
deprecation_warnings=False in ansible.cfg.
ok: [user2]

TASK [create an empty file] ******************************************
changed: [user2]

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************
user1                      : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
user2                      : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Works only on one vm but not the second.

- **user1 is ubuntu server with cli**
- **user2 is debian with cli**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not how you define users in an *ini* format of the inventory.

This point and the specific user use case is covered under: [assigning a variable to one machine: host variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#assigning-a-variable-to-one-machine-host-variables), where you can see that users have to be assigned using `ansible_user=foo`

So your hosts files should read:

```
[servers]
my_ubuntu_server ansible_host=192.168.56.4 ansible_user=user1
my_debian_server ansible_host=192.168.56.3 ansible_user=user2
```

The aliases of the hosts there does not really matter, as long as you specify an `ansible_host`, it's whatever fits you best to understand on which node Ansible is currently running.
Worth reading: [inventory aliases](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#inventory-aliases).